# Como saco los valores de cada variable del array y la meto en una variable

Tags: php

Necesito sacar los varlores de las variables de un array y meterlas en diferente variables pero no soy capaz. Con esto

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto){
$pt1 = $producto['titulo'];
$pp1 = $producto['precio'];
}
```

saco una pero y el resto como lo hago?esto un poco pegado en php

Comment: Ahí asignas cada valor a `$pt1` y `$pp1` respectivamente. ¿Qué es lo que quieres haces? ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: quiero hacer como si fuera java un for(int i=0;i< cesta.length;i++){ String pt[i] =cesta.get[i].getTitulo e igual con precio, de esta manera detener ppt1 el producto 1 de la cesta ppt2 el producto 2 pp1 el precio del primer producto pp2 el del segundo etc

Comment: No entiendo para qué quieres hacer eso ¿? No sabes cuántos productos podrá haber, no le veo sentido a crear variables con esos datos... ¿para qué fines? Teniendo la variable de sesión ya tienes los datos ¿no? ¿Por qué quieres guardarlos en variables? ¿Si son 10,000 productos, vas a crear 10,000 variables?

Comment: porque necesito crear un pdf a modo de factura y para ello he de llamarlos a cada proudcto y su precio de laguna forma y se me a ocurrido esa a ti se te ocurre otra?

Comment: Dentro del `foreach` puedes concatenar todo en una sola variable  y luego usas esa variable para mostrar los datos en el PDF o donde quieras. Por ejemplo: `$mData="";  foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto){
$mData.="Título: $producto[titulo] Precio: $producto[precio] \n";
} //Y fuera del bucle usas $mData para lo que quieras` Eso es sólo un ejemplo simple. Puedes hacer cosas más complejas, como una tabla con filas y columnas...

Comment: vale, siguiente pregunta con eso que me has dicho como hago el total de precios?y si pongo $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $mData, 0, 0, 'l'); me pone todo lo que hay del tiron?

Comment: Debes pulsar en [edit] y explicarte mejor, mostrando qué estructura tiene el array. O si te refieres a mostrar el total al final de una tabla por ejemplo. Puedes ir acumulando el total en una variable aparte dentro del bucle y luego mostrarla.

Comment: Si fuera java se hacerlo pero en Php no tengo ni idea. pues el total es la suma de precios de too lo que hay en la cesta. Pues la estructura del array de la cesta es esta  $producto['nombre'] = $_POST['nombre'];
                                $producto['precio'] = $_POST['precio'];
                                $producto['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];
                                $producto['img'] = $_POST['img'];
                                $_SESSION['cesta'][$_POST['producto']] = $producto;
                            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de un bucle puedes concatenar la información en una variable y luego usar esa variable para mostrarla donde quieras, por ejemplo:

```
#Variable que usaremos para concatenar los datos
$mData="";
#Variable para el total de precios
$mTotal=0;

foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto){
    #En PHP se usa .= para concatenar
    $mData.="Título: $producto[titulo] Precio: $producto[precio] \n";
    #En PHP se usa += para sumar a la misma variable
    $mTotal+=$producto['precio'];
}
#Fuera del bucle, tendrás todo lo que recogiste dentro
#Hacemos una prueba
echo $mData.PHP_EOL;
echo $mTotal;
```

Así como eso, puedes hacer más cosas, como por ejemplo crear una tabla con los datos organizados en filas y columnas.

Comment: El /n del $mData no lo respeta

Comment: @Carlos24345 lo puedes cambiar por `PHP_EOL`, por ejemplo: `$mData.="Título: $producto[titulo] Precio: $producto[precio]".PHP_EOL;` (OJO, PHP_EOL iría fuera de las comillas) o si lo vas a mostrar en un contexto HTML puedes ponerlo así: `$mData.="Título: $producto[titulo] Precio: $producto[precio] <br />";`

Comment: Ninguna de las 2 me vale no me hace el salto de linea

Comment: @Carlos24345 ¿en qué contexto exactamente estás mostrando los datos?

Comment: En fpdf unalibreria para pdf

Comment: Es posible que haga falta alguna configuración para que admita los saltos de línea. Sugiero que des esta pregunta por resuelta y abras otra pregunta sobre ese tema en concreto, mostrando el código que usas para mostrar los datos en PDF, @Carlos24345

Comment: Vale funciona era cuestion de poner el multicell. Pero hay un problema la idea seria que los precio estuvieran alineados uno debajo de otro como si fuera una factura real.

Comment: @Carlos24345 supongo que `fpdf` tendrá configuraciones para alinear los datos, o admitirá tablas o algo así. Eso es ya más propio de la librería. Si tienes algún problema sobre ella puedes preguntar en una nueva pregunta, poniendo también la etiqueta `fpdf`, de modo que alguien que conozca esa librería te pueda ayudar en ese aspecto.

Comment: oki gracias voy a ello